# SpringBootTest with MockBean is not returning what I expect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test, spring-boot-test

Versions:

```
Java: 1.8
Spring Boot: 1.5.4.RELEASE
```

Application Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootMockitoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    MyCoolService myCoolService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootMockitoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(myCoolService.talkToMe());
    }
}
```

My Service Interface:

```
public interface MyCoolService {
  public String talkToMe();
}
```

My Service Implementation:

```
@Service
public class MyCoolServiceImpl implements MyCoolService {

  @Override
  public String talkToMe() {
    return "Epic Win";
  }
}
```

My Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringbootMockitoApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private MyCoolService myCoolService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(myCoolService.talkToMe()).thenReturn("I am greater than epic");

    }

}
```

Expected Output: I am greater than epic
Actual Output: null

I simply want to replace the bean instance in the context with a mock that will return "I am greater than epic".  Have I misconfigured something here?

Comment: I ran the test with the same classes mentioned above and the same Spring Boot version, and it works fine with no problems. In your `pom.xml`, did you add both `spring-boot-starter-test` and `spring-boot-test` dependencies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `run` method of any `CommandLineRunner`s is called as part of `SpringApplication` being run. This happens when the test framework is bootstrapping the application context for your tests. Crucially, this is before your test method has set any expectations on your `MyCoolService` mock. As a result the mock returns `null` when `talkToMe()` is called.

Something may have been lost in reducing your problem to a simple example, but I don't think I'd use an integration test here. Instead, I'd unit test your `CommandLineRunner` with a mock service. To so so, I'd recommend moving to constructor injection so that you can pass the mock directly into the service's constructor.

Comment: This application structure was meant for a batch process that runs on startup for testing would it make more sense to disable the commandLineRunner somehow and replicate the logic in the runner?